# How to make Zombienet test files from a docker-compose yaml file?

Tags: docker, zombienet, kubernetes

I have tested the Zombienet example network definition and feature files with default images.
How can I test my custom parachain?

I have an existing docker-compose yaml file

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  collator:
    container_name: collator
    image: pnetwork/collator
    ports:
      - "30343:30343"
      - "40333:40333"
      - "6969:6969"
      - "8844:8844"
      - "9977:9977"
    command: bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/parachain-collator --alice --collator --force-authoring --chain rococo-local --unsafe-ws-external --parachain-id 2000 --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe --base-path /tmp/parachain/alice --port 40333 --ws-port 8844 --rpc-port 6969 --rpc-cors all -- --execution wasm --chain res/dev/rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30343 --ws-port 9977 > collator.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"
    depends_on:
      - charlie-relay
  alice-relay:
    container_name: alice-relay
    image: pnetwork/relay
    ports:
      - "30333:30333"
      - "9944:9944"
    command: bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/polkadot --alice --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/alice --chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe > alice.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"

  bob-relay:
    container_name: bob-relay
    image: pnetwork/relay
    ports:
      - "30334:30334"
      - "9945:9945"
    command: bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/polkadot --bob --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/bob --chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30334 --ws-port 9945 --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe > bob.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"

  charlie-relay:
    container_name: charlie-relay
    image: pnetwork/relay
    ports:
      - "30335:30335"
      - "9946:9946"
    command: bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/polkadot --charlie --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/charlie --chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30335 --ws-port 9946 --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe > charlie.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: jacogr/polkadot-js-apps:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - collator
```

From the example 0001-small-network.toml file, I keep default_command and default_args the same, but override them in each relay chain node via `commandWithArgs`

Then I copied alice relay chain node command from above and pasted them into my 0001-small-network.toml as

```
  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true
  commandWithArgs = 'bash -c... "..." '
```

But how about alice node's ports from the docker-compose yaml file? the copied command has ports in it...

About parachain collator, I copied its command from the docker-compose yaml file. but how about the ports again?
My parachain command has port values in it, too...

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true
  commandWithArgs = 'bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/polkadot --alice --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/alice --chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe > alice.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"'

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true
  commandWithArgs = 'bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/polkadot --bob --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/bob --chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30334 --ws-port 9945 --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe > bob.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"'

[[parachains]]
id = 100

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "..."
  command = 'bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/parachain-collator --alice --collator --force-authoring --chain rococo-local --unsafe-ws-external --parachain-id 2000 --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe --base-path /tmp/parachain/alice --port 40333 --ws-port 8844 --rpc-port 6969 --rpc-cors all -- --execution wasm --chain res/dev/rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30343 --ws-port 9977 > collator.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"'

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

Is that the correct way to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things that jumped at me looking at those configurations:

- `apt-get install -y wget;` should be done as part of the container setup, if you need this, derive another container from `docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18`
- `nohup` is not necessary and not useful in this context. One usually wants all the logs.
- `bash -c` is not really needed for a single command
- redirecting output to files in the container is not recommended, it's best to use dedicated logging infra for kubernetes

---

Generally one should not provide the port arguments unless explicitly needed and let zombienet figure those out as much as possible. Zombienet will add cli flags, and expectes the `command` specified to understand substrate cli flags, so either a `substrate` based chain, `polkadot`, or in the case of liveness/sec tests `malus` based nemesis nodes.

Comment: As @drahnr mention ZombieNet will add some cli flags needed to work (like ports) but also will make some customization in the chain-spec (e.g. set the validators keys). Can your chain-spec (rococo-custom-2-raw.json) be generated in plain format by the collator? If not you can use the `chain_spec_path` to use the pre-generated one but you will need more configurations in the nodes.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: To give a bit more context: `docker-compose` as toy deployment tool and serves a different purpose than what a more tailored integration testing tool does. The integration tool makes some assumptions about the binaries deployed. It's not meant as a replacement or general purpose tool. It's sole purpose is to simplify the deployments of ad-hoc test networks and have per node assertion integrations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the default command in polkadot relaychain, but add your collator command, which is target/release/parachain-collator if your parachain is based on substrate-parachain-template. Notice there is no DOT "." before the command!

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "gcr.io/p-network/collator:latest"
  command = "target/release/parachain-collator"
  
[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```